# Update two models using yii x-editable

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions, x-editable

So, I'm using this extension: [x-editable for yii](http://x-editable.demopage.ru/).

And I'm currently trying to update two models in **update()** function.

I have two models:

> **Realisasi.php**
>
> **RealisasiDeadline.php**.

So when a cell is updated on table **Realisasi.php** (one value in column ***t1701*** in this case), I want the function to update the corresponding value in column ***t1701*** of table **RealisasiDeadline**, using column ***no*** as the foreign key.

Since I haven't found any example on Google, I made it up myself:

```
public function actionSimpanEdit($kode) {
    Yii::import('editable.EditableSaver');
    $es = new EditableSaver($_GET['model']);  // 'modelName' is classname of model to be updated
    $es->update();

    $es2 = RealisasiDeadline::model()->findByPk($kode);//this is where I'm stuck
    $es2['t1701'] = '1991-11-19';//this too
    $es->update();//and this
}
```

This is the view.php:

```
array(
        'name' => 't1701',
        'value' => 'CHtml::value($data,"hubtarget.t1701")=== "0"?"Target Nol":$data->t1701',
        'header' => 'Bkl Selatan',
        'class' => 'editable.EditableColumn',
        'editable' => array(
            'url' => $this->createUrl('simpanEdit', array('model' => 'Realisasi', 'kode'=>'$data->no')),
        )
    ),
```

What have I missed? Is it possible at all to do? If not, is there another solution?

**UPDATE**
It's not showing any error. But the value in table **RealisasiDeadline** doesn't change, only the one in **Realisasi** does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added some comments to original function so you can improve upon it. Biggest issue with this code is that looking at it I have no idea what it does.

```
public function actionSimpanEdit($kode) {
        Yii::import('editable.EditableSaver'); // Should be at the top of the file
        // For the love of god use descriptive variable names
        $es = new EditableSaver($_GET['model']); // Would prefer to have model as actions argument
        $es->update();

        $es2 = RealisasiDeadline::model()->findByPk($kode); // no idea what this model is responsible for
        $es2['t1701'] = '1991-11-19'; // no idea what attribute t1701 is, use descriptive names
        $es->update();
    }
```

I have refactored it a bit. Still have no idea what it does ;/

```
public function actionSimpanEdit($id, $model) {
        $editableSaver = new EditableSaver($model);
        $editableSaver->update();

        $deadline = RealisasiDeadline::model()->findByPk($id);

        if($deadline instanceof RealisasiDeadline) {
            $deadline->t1701 = '1991-11-19';
            if(!$deadline->update()) {
                // something went wrong
            }
        } else {
            // not found
        }
    }
```

Going back to your problem. It is probably caused by RealisasiDeadline model being not found or some behavior or event preventing it from update.